# How does Hocus Focus run automatically at login?

Tags: macos, applications, login-items

I've been using an application "Hocus Focus" ever since I upgraded to a MacBook M1 running Big Sur (I don't remember what I was using before, but it wasn't compatible).

Today I upgraded to Monterey, and Hocus Focus crashes when it starts, so I want to disable it from starting automatically at login. Normally you enable/disable this feature with a checkbox in its settings dialogue. But since it crashes, you can't use this. It's a menubar item, not a Dock application, so you can't uncheck the "Open at Login" option there.

I can't figure out how it's starting automatically, so that I can disable it some other way.  I looked in my Login Items in the Users & Groups system preference, but it's not there. And I looked for something in `~/Library/LaunchAgents`, but nothing in there starts it. I even searched all of `/Library` and `/System/Library` for anything with "hocus" in its name, but there was nothing.

The [developer's website](http://hocusfoc.us/) is also broken, so I can't contact them for tech support.

Anyone have any other ideas where to look for its automatic starting?